# Check for an instance of ArrayBufferView?

Tags: javascript, instanceof, arraybuffer, typedarray

### Background

With a bit of research I've found that, although `ArrayBufferView` wasn't initially exposed (through [NoInterfaceObject]) there appeared to be broad agreement that it should be, due to my described use case.

- [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=796327)
- [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60449)
- [Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105605)

The initial agreement was to expose the `ArrayBufferView` constructor on the `DOMWindow` namespace, which was implemented in Safari (and still works in 6.1.1) and Chrome, but was then [pulled from Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247561) in favour of a static method `ArrayBuffer.isView()`.

Meanwhile, Mozilla are (still) [talking about implementing](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=896105) `ArrayBuffer.isView()`.

#### In brief:

- Safari exposes the `ArrayBufferView` constructor
- Chrome has `ArrayBuffer.isView()`
- Firefox has nothing
- IE - I haven't even got near yet...

### Question

So, my question. What's the most succinct way to check if an object is an instance of ArrayBufferView?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use either:

```
function isAbv(value) {
    return value && value.buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer && value.byteLength !== undefined;
}
```

or:

```
var ArrayBufferView = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(new Uint8Array)).constructor;
function isAbv(value) {
    return value instanceof ArrayBufferView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better answer I guess:

```
var arr = new Float64Array(100);

arr instanceof (new Uint16Array()).constructor.prototype.__proto__.constructor //true
```

works in Chrome & Firefox, maybe other browsers too

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayBuffer.isView` is [supported on all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=isview).

```js
const b = new Uint8Array()
ArrrayBuffer.isView(b) // true
```