# Server Sent Events in Firefox Shared Web Workers

Tags: html, firefox, web-worker, server-sent-events

I am attempting to use an `EventSource` (Server Sent Events) within a Shared Web Worker in Firefox. When I attempt to try and use the EventSource constructor in the message event in the Shared Worker, the Worker throws an error `ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined.`

I assume this means this object can't be accessed in the Shared Web Workers context but I am able to access the EventSource from within a Shared Web Worker in Google Chrome. **I want to make it clear that I can use `EventSource` without issue if used directly from script, I just have issues with creating and using it inside of a Shared Web Worker within Firefox.**

Looking at the [EventSource spec in Section 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/#the-eventsource-interface) it states:

> This constructor must be visible when the script's global object is either a Window object or an object implementing the WorkerUtils interface.

But looking at the [Web Workers spec in Section 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#apis-available-to-workers) the interface specified there is a 
WorkerUtils interface.

```
interface WorkerGlobalScope : EventTarget {
    readonly attribute WorkerGlobalScope self;
    readonly attribute WorkerLocation location;

    void close();
    [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? onerror;
    [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? onoffline;
    [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? ononline;
};
WorkerGlobalScope implements WorkerUtils;
```

I would have assumed I could access the EventSource using `self.EventSource` or just `EventSource` from within the Worker based on the information mentioned in both specs. However this doesn't seem to be the case in practice with Firefox.

**Is there a reason why I cannot access an EventSource from a Shared Web Worker from Firefox?**

*I want to use a Shared Web Worker for EventSource (Push Events) because a user could have multiple tabs open from the website in question and I want to avoid having the browser open up multiple EventSource connections to the host.*

**Is there another approach I should be using instead?** Unfortunately Web Sockets isn't an option as I am developing on ASP.net 2.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for an instance of ArrayBufferView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753581/check-for-an-instance-of-arraybufferview)

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this problem? I am stuck at the same problem and need a solution. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The solution currently is to use a polyfill, see Mike's question [How to make EventSource available inside SharedWorker in FireFox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321295/how-to-make-eventsource-available-inside-sharedworker-in-firefox)

Comment: There is a Firefox bug open for native EventSource in worker: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=876498

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has being fixed in Firefox Nightly and shipped in Firefox 53:

> I've exposed EventSource to dedicated worker and shared worker.
>
> Do other browser engines implement this? 
>   As I know, Chrome supports it in dedicated worker, shared worker, and service worker. Safari supports it in dedicated worker. Edge doesn't support it.
>
> Expose EventSource to ServiceWorker: 
>   No plan for Service Worker at this moment because there is an open issue https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/947 under discussion.

**References**

- [Mozilla Bug 1267903 – EventSource for workers](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267903)
- [Firefox Releases: 53 - Workers and Service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/53#Workers_and_service_workers)
- [Future Releases | Be the first to know what's new with upcoming Firefox releases.](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/)
- [Intent to ship: EventSource for Dedicated Worker and Shared Worker - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/UEEnz_2-Oos)
- [web-platform-tests/eventsource at master · w3c/web-platform-tests](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/tree/master/eventsource)